# Cisco regex match this but not that

Tags: regex, cisco

I have the following string in a much larger config:

```
as-path-set DAVE-9999-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-9999-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-55555-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-44444-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-33333-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-11111-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-22222-CBG
```

I would like to match all of these lines **except** for the lines that contain 9999. I don't understand the negation regex well enough to make this work. Can someone help. The ideal output will be:

```
as-path-set DAVE-55555-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-44444-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-33333-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-11111-CBG
as-path-set DAVE-22222-CBG
```

Comment: Are the numbers always repeated or is `as-path-set DAVE-13547-CBG` a possible match? Is the text always the same? Is `as-path-set DAVE-99999-CBG` possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
^as-path-set DAVE-(?!9999)[0-9]+-CBG$
```

Answer (score 1):

With a negative lookbehind, and knowing that all your lines end to a specific string:

```
.*(?<![9]{4}-CBG)$
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/uP2rH3)

Comment: Might want to use `.*(?<!-[9]{4}-CBG)$` if you don't want it to match the 5 nines case. Also, why not just `.*(?<!9999-CBG)$`, rather than use the `{}` op?

Comment: @Mark OP says a line that contains 9999, so five nines also has a 4 nines in it, and about 9999 in regex, that's just a manner of coding.

Comment: It wasn't clear that he actually meant 4-or-more 9s so I was just offering an alternative. The same with the alternate coding, when you're teaching someone something new and subtle like negative lookbehinds, simplify everything else. It helps.